# open the same pic in another layout in fitXY size

Tags: android

i am new in android, and i want to open a pic in another layout which was already opened in previous layout but size was small. After clicking the imageview the same pic i want to open in fitXY size in another layout.

Comment: if you have tried any code then post here.

Comment: What you tried?? So, that we can help you further..

Comment: Do you want that - if user clicks an image in 1st layout and when click it should be opened in 2nd layout with fitXY size ?